# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin for json

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using this ajax to call a json file but somehow I kept receiving this error message : "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

This is my code to call from my school intranet URL.

```
$.ajax({
type:"get",
url:"http://172.20.192.218:8080/DC_Local/rest/datacorrelation?type=/soccer/football_team&limit=20",
dataType: json,
success: function(data){
var pts = [];
$.each(json.data, function(i,v){
    pts.push([v.topic, v.audience.length]);
});
},

error: function (){
alert("Error"); 
}
});
```

this is my json structure:

```
"data": [
                     {
                         "id": "/en/chelsea_fc",
                         "topic": "Chelsea F.C.",
                         "audience": [
                             {
                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Didier Drogba"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Frank Lampard"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     }
                                 ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Didier Drogba"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Frank Lampard"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     }
                                 ]
                             }
                         ],
                         "type": "/soccer/football_team"
                     },
                     {
                         "id": "/en/manchester_united_fc",
                         "topic": "Manchester United F.C.",
                         "audience": [
                             {
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Ryan Giggs"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Manchester United"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Manchester United"
                                     }
                                 ],
                                 "userid": "100003921730958"
                             }
                         ],
                         "type": "/soccer/football_team"
                     }
                 ]
             }
```

Comment: you must use jsonp insted of ajax

Comment: This is called [Same origin Policy](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy). You can't do a plain ajax call to a domain not the same as the domain your document resides in. You need to do a [`jsonp`](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) request or set a allow-origin header on the server side.